# A question on Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, divisors-algebraic-geometry

As an exercise for myself I wanted to check GRR in the following situation. Consider $P:X \rightarrow B$ to be an Weierstrass elliptic fibration with a section, and $X\times_B X$ be the fiber product with $\pi_{1,2}$ be the corresponding projections to the first and second factor. Then from GRR we have,

$ch(R\pi_{2*} \mathcal{O}_{X\times_B X})=\pi_{2*} \big(ch(\mathcal{O}_{X\times_B X})\cdot \pi_1^* Td (X/B)\big) = \\ \pi_{2*} \big[\pi_1^*\big(1-\frac{1}{2}P^* c_1(B)+\frac{13}{12} P^* c_1^2(B)+\sigma P^*c_1(B)-\frac{1}{2}\sigma P^* c_1^2(B)\big)\big]$.

where $\sigma$ is the section. So obviously the left hand side is 1, but I cannot show why the right hand side should be 1.

$\textbf{I forgot to put the higher direct image in the LHS, so it's not 1 necessrily}$

Base $B$, is a surface (can be projective space, or Hirtzebruch), and maybe I should mention that $\sigma^2=-c_1(B)\sigma$

Let's be more specific, if I'm right we can use the following commutative diagram,

$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X\times_B X @>{\pi_1}>> X\\ @V{\pi_2}VV @VV{P_1}V\\
X @>>{P_2}> B
\end{CD}$

Then $\pi_{2*}o \pi_1^* \sim P_{2}^* o P_{1*} $. So we can use the projection formula. Now the specific questions are,

$P_{*}(\sigma)=?$

$P_{*}(1)=?$.

Naively both should be 1, but it cannot be true...

Comment: I edited the question, but still, it would be nice to compute the left-hand side independently

Comment: For answer refer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/294659/a-question-on-grothendieck-riemann-roch/294667#294667